# want to remove libboost1.65 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, boost, ubuntu-18.04

the result of

sudo apt install libboost1.65-dev
==>

```
sudo apt install libboost1.65-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cmake-data libcurl4 librhash0 libuv1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  libboost1.65-doc libmpfrc++-dev libntl-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libboost1.65-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 76 not upgraded.
112 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/7,218 kB of archives.
After this operation, 119 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 217405 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libboost1.65-dev_1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost1.65-dev:amd64 (1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.65-dev_1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp', which is also in package libboost1.67-dev 1.67-0~5~ubuntu18.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.65-dev_1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

sudo apt autoremove

or

sudo apt remove libboost1.65-dev

or

install other versions of libboost 
==>

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-atomic1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-chrono1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-container1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-context1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-coroutine1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-date-time1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev but it is not installed
 libboost-exception1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-fiber1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-filesystem1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-graph-parallel1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-graph1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-iostreams1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-locale1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-log1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-math1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-mpi1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-program-options1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-python1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-random1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-regex1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-serialization1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-signals1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-stacktrace1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-system1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-test1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-thread1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-timer1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-type-erasure1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
 libboost-wave1.65-dev : Depends: libboost1.65-dev (= 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

result said 
`You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.`

sudo apt ---fix-broken install==>

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cmake-data libcurl4 librhash0 libuv1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libboost1.65-dev
Suggested packages:
  libboost1.65-doc libmpfrc++-dev libntl-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libboost1.65-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 76 not upgraded.
112 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/7,218 kB of archives.
After this operation, 119 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 217405 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libboost1.65-dev_1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost1.65-dev:amd64 (1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.65-dev_1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp', which is also in package libboost1.67-dev 1.67-0~5~ubuntu18.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.65-dev_1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I guess the reason of these errors is because

carsh of libboost 1.65 and 1.67 version.

I trired to remove usr/lib/booost, but same result happened

anyone help me? thank you!

formatting ubuntu is a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove everything boost-dev-related with a command like `apt remove 'libboost.*-dev'` (but **carefully look through** what apt is trying to remove before saying "yes").